# Android: Errors occured during the build?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dexguard

I am attempting to run `DEXguard` on my simple android application.

I have taken the step of adding it's `JAR` file into the `dropins` directory in my 
 `Eclipse` ADT bundle.

However now whenever I open eclipse I get this error:

```
    Errors occurred during the build. 
Errors running builder "Android optimizer and obfuscator (Dexguard) on project 'test'.

    com/android/sdklib/util/GrabProcessOutput$IPProcessOutput
```

Anytime I try to run any project within eclipse this happens.

What can I do to **fix this problem?**

EDIT: I have already re-installed eclipse and updated my sdk

Answer (score 0):

Such an error is a sign that you're combining the DexGuard plugin with an incompatible version of the Android plugin in Eclipse. You should check the compatible version numbers that are documented in the DexGuard manual. Upgrading both plugins to the latest versions should work.